# How to update an array inside of a Laravel Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a multi-dimensional array being passed from a 3rd party source which I'm turning into an Illuminate Collection object and doing a group-by.

So it is retuning me the data like so:

```
{
    #items: array:2 [
        "123H0002" => Collection{
            #items: array:1 [
                0 => array:12 [
                    "account" => "12345",
                    "id" => "456",
                    "name" => "Dave",
                    ...
                ]
            ]
        }
        "456854456456" => Collection{
            #items: array:1 [
                0 => array:12 [
                    "account" => "4657456",
                    "id" => "123",
                    "name" => "Geoff",
                    ...
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm then looping over this to process each group of collections together.

```
foreach($data as $items){
    $this->process($items)
}
```

Then inside of the process method, I want to add items to the array inside of the collection but it seems to fail to save.

```
public function process($data)
{
    foreach($data as $item){
        $item['status'] = 'NEW';
    }
    
    $this->db->insert_batch('imported_data', $data->toArray());
}
```

Now the problem here is $item['status'] is there when I debug the contents of the $item array inside of the foreach loop however this change isn't reflected in the final $data collection when its converted to an array.

What am I missing for updating an array inside of a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can´t update the array cause is passed by value, for modify the content u need pass by reference like this:

```
foreach($data as &$item){
    $item['status'] = 'NEW';
}
```

don´t forget to unset the reference:

```
unset($item);
```

I think it's best to avoid this pitfall altogether and just write foreach loops that have to manipulate the original array the normal way:

```
foreach($data as $index => $entry) {
    $data[$index] = ...
}
```

[here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) you will get more info about reference variables.